# How to modify or override a core function (wp_star_rating)

Tags: functions

I'm looking for the way to modify a core function, in this case the wp_star_rating() function, declared in wp-admin/includes/template.php
Actually what I want is to change the $title variable, cause I want to traslate that string.
I'm working with a child theme, so I'm wondering if is it possible maybe with a filter...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `wp_star_rating` being called?

Comment: On further inspection, all the strings in that function are already translatable, including what is assigned to the internal `$title` variable, but if you're using this in your theme, why not just create a new function that does the same thing but with that minor difference? It looks like the title variable is only used to aid with screen readers

Comment: Hi Tom
Thanks for replying!
It's not a bad idea to create a new function, although I would prefer to use wp_star_rating and translate that string.
I want to translate it because is also displayed in SERPs.